# mpv video freezes but audio plays when using youtube

Tags: audio, video, cache, youtube-dl, mpv

I'm using [`mpv`](https://mpv.io/) to play videos from different sources (e.g. `youtube`) in conjunction with my newsfeed-reader [`newsboat`](https://newsboat.org/) on my `Debian Stable` system (actually `PureOS Amber` which is based on `Debian`).  But while this often works fine, sometimes `mpv` stops playing the video-part (so the moving images) and gets stuck in a frozen image, while the audio still continues to work and progresses normally.

I posted an image of what that looks like (so the audio plays in `mpv` but video stopped working and froze) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOLHR.png) since it isn't allowed to add images if you don't have enough reputation (maybe someone could edit this post and include the image directly).

I can often resolve this by reloading the video (either restarting `mpv` or using the plugin [`reload.lua`](https://github.com/4e6/mpv-reload)) although then it might just get stuck some minutes later.  Also I have the impression that when changing the format of the played video using the plugin [`youtube-quality`](https://github.com/jgreco/mpv-youtube-quality) to an mp4-based format this happens less, but that might just be a personal bios.  Regardless, it's annoying.

I assume that this is a caching issue.  I have the following, possibly relevant lines in my personal dotfiles and software versions:

~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf:

```
ytdl-raw-options=prefer-free-formats=
ytdl-format='bestvideo[height<=360][ext=webm]+bestaudio[ext=webm]/bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio/bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best'
cache=yes
demuxer-max-bytes=400MiB
demuxer-max-back-bytes=100MiB
```

~/.config/youtube-dl/config

```
--prefer-free-formats
-f 'bestvideo[height<=480][ext=webm]+bestaudio[ext=webm]/bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio/bestvideo+bestaudio/best'
```

mpv --version

```
mpv 0.29.1 Copyright © 2000-2018 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on UNKNOWN
ffmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       56.14.100 (runtime 56.22.100)
   libavcodec      58.18.100 (runtime 58.35.100)
   libavformat     58.12.100 (runtime 58.20.100)
   libswscale      5.1.100 (runtime 5.3.100)
   libavfilter     7.16.100 (runtime 7.40.101)
   libswresample   3.1.100 (runtime 3.3.100)
ffmpeg version: 4.1.6-1~deb10u1
```

youtube-dl --version

```
2020.12.09
```

Comment: Related issue on mpv's bugtracker : https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/8779